# how do i add a dynamiclally generating dropdown to the layout.phtml in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

i want to add a dropdown menu to my layout .
i have a list of hotels . i want to change the hotel from a dropdown , i need to keep that drop down in my layout.phtml .
problem is hotel list is dynamic.
can i do this , is this possible in zend ,

here is my layout,phtml

i need to add a dropdown to `<div class="floatright wid35 textaligncenter padtop5">`

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $this->docType(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headStyle(); ?>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $this->render('admin/header.phtml'); ?>


<div id="contentColumns" class="columns">
    <div id="columnRight" class="column-right"></div>
    <div id="columnLeft" class="column-right">
        <div class="link-guide">
            <div id="breadcrumbs" class="floatleft wid60">
                <?php echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setLinkLast(false)->setMinDepth(0)->render(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="floatright wid35 textaligncenter padtop5">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="padding-box">
            <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>       
</div>                  

<?php echo $this->render('admin/footer.phtml'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually ,  the case is that form should be appear in all my pages ,

Answer (score 3):

No. Layout files represent the static structure of a page like header and footer and everything you wrap around your dynamic content.

So this is not recommended. However you could solve that implementing the `_init` method of your main controller and extend any controller with that main controller:

```
class MainController extends Zend_Action_Controller{

    function init(){
        $this->view->foo = "Show everywhere!";
    }
}

class IndexController extends MainController{

    public function indexAction(){
        $this->view->bar = "Show only on index/index";
    }
}
```

Or you can use a plugin which would be the more elegant way

```
class MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){

        $view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::
                      getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->view;

        $view->foo = "bar";
    }
}
```

and in your bootstrap process register that plugin

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->registerPlugin(new MyPlugin);
```

Comment: mm....... trying to understand this . i ll be able to do this  . thanks for the help guys  :D :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create preDispatch function in your base controller class.
Then you get hotel list and send it to view:

```
$this->view->hotels = $hotels;
```

And in your layout you can parse it as you wish.

Comment: Also you can put logic for create dropdown to partial( for clean layout)

Comment: why posting a dublicate of my answer?

Comment: I think that bootstrap is wrong place for this functional, but i could be wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here:

1. Using your hotel list in a dropdown suggests that you will have a form `My_Form_Hotels` extending `Zend_Form` which accepts the hotel list as a constructor parameter.
2. Where should you populate the hotel list, instantiate the form, and communicate all this to the view/layout for rendering?

Sounds like a [front controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) would do the job. Since the layout resource functions as a plugin that runs late in `postDispatch()`, you need to run yours before that. `dispatchLoopStartup()` should be fine.

Something like this in `library/My/Plugin/HotelForm.php`:

```
class My_Plugin_HotelForm extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $hotelModel = new My_Model_Hotel();
        $hotels = $hotelModel->getAllHotels();
        $form = new My_Form_Hotels($hotels);
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
        $view = $viewRenderer->getView();
        $view->hotelForm = $form;
    }
}
```

Then in your layout, simply dump the form using `$this->hotelForm`.

To enable your plugin, add to `application/configs/application.ini`:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = 'My_"
resources.frontcontroller.plugins[] = "My_Plugin_HotelForm"
```