# run an action in all of pages

Tags: zend-framework, layout, action

i need to show variables in part of layout(i know placeholder is useful!) but this variables assigning in actions of controller, so i need render of view be after action running and this variables will show in all of pages (like menu but not exastly).

some of actions load with ajax!

what is your idea?! what is best way?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question and are more detials. It is difficult to infer what is being ask. So, you want to assign some placeholder variable for every action, but you don't want to do it 'manually' within your actions? Maybe some plugin controller?

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896014/how-do-i-add-a-dynamiclally-generating-dropdown-to-the-layout-phtml-in-zend-frame/5896902#5896902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, Action Helpers might be what you are looking for.  Take a look at the documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html